# Facebook Pixel not tracking hashbang URLs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I've been using the [Facebook-Pixel-Angular module](https://github.com/mooyoul/angulartics-facebook-pixel) and everything seems to be tracking fine. However, none of the URLS are being tracked in the Facebook Pixel Dashboard-- Only the base URL is tracked. For example, if I go to example.com/#!/hello, then only example.com is tracked.

One potential solution I had was to do a GET request directly to Facebook's API via this URL: https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=PIXEL_ID_HERE&ev=PageView&dl=ENCODED_URL_TO_TRACK_HERE&rl=&if=false&ts=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_HERE&v=2.5.0&pv=visible

This GET request works perfectly when visiting the URL directly via the browser, but I recieve this error when making the request via the JS code: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Any ideas on how I can allow the tracking of hashbang URLs? Unfortunately I do not have the option to remove the hashbang without heavily altering the entire backend.

Comment: might be it'll help you. have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/57182368/8530893