# Using Facebook advertising tracking pixels in Angular 2 / 4

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook

I'm trying to work out how I use the Facebook tracking pixel with my angular project.

I have added the base pixel into my index.html

but I want to fire an event from the javascript, how do I fire this

```js
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
```

Angular will not compile when I have this in my code as it can't find fbq

Answer (score 8):

Even though `fbq` is globally-available in your app at runtime, the compiler doesn't know about it because it is defined in `index.html` (outside of the typescript files known to the compiler).

To fix this, add an **ambient declaration** to the files where you use `fbq`, like so:

```
declare const fbq: any; // 1. add an ambient declaration

@Component({...})
export class ComponentUsingFacebookPixel {

  fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration'); // 2. This will compile now

}
```

This doesn't change the compiled javascript or overwrite the value of `fbq`; it's a promise to the compiler that there will be a value by that name available at runtime.

You can provide a more specific type than `any` if you'd like additional help from the compiler, but `any` is sufficient to avoid the compilation error you're seeing.

Comment: Declarelation throw error. Any other way to acheive this?

Comment: Maybe try to use this like the Angular website's [Google Analytics service](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/aio/src/app/shared/ga.service.ts), which is also defined an object in `index.html`

Answer (score 5):

create one service and call it in your app.component.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FacebookPixelService {
        constructor() { }
        load() {
            (function (f: any, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
                if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                    n.callMethod ?
                        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
                }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
                n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
                t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            (window as any).fbq.disablePushState = true; //not recommended, but can be done
            (window as any).fbq('init', '<your id>');
            (window as any).fbq('track', 'PageView');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

add this in `ngOnInit()` if you have already added to index.html

```
(window as any).fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration'); // this Worked for me
```